# Eliminar duplicados según propiedad de un array de objetos

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando eliminar duplicados de un array de objetos, el problema que tengo es que no sé como decirle especificamente que compare esa propiedad, este es mi objetos:

```
    var results : [{Cantidad: "           1.000"
Centro: "4000"
CreadoEl: "20200306"
Estado: "ABIE"
Lote: "0001"
LoteInspeccion: "040001247553"
Material: "43628096159"
Orden: "100000680258"
PedidoCliente: "1020000076"
Posicion: "000010"},

{Cantidad: "           1.000"
Centro: "4000"
CreadoEl: "20200630"
Estado: "ABIE"
Lote: "0001"
LoteInspeccion: "040001275449"
Material: "43628098228"
Orden: "100000710155"
PedidoCliente: "1020000074"
Posicion: "000010"},

{Cantidad: "           1.000"
Centro: "4000"
CreadoEl: "20200630"
Estado: "ABIE"
Lote: "0004"
LoteInspeccion: "040001275455"
Material: "43628098228"
Orden: "100000732763"
PedidoCliente: "1020000074"
Posicion: "000020"}]
```

Ahora, lo que quiero es eliminar los "Lotes" repetidos, es decir el resultado seria un array de dos posiciones, no importa cual se elimine ya que solo me interesa un array de Lotes.

Intente con Filter, reduce y Set pero no me funcionaron puede que porque los usé mal jeje, no quiero hacer un for sino me gustaría ir usando formas mas prolijas para hacer mis desarrollos

Alguien me echa una manito ¿?

Comment: Dices que has realizado varios intentos, pero **no muestras ninguno de ellos**. Tal y como lo estás planteando, es un `hacedlo para mi`. Muestra algún intento por tu parte, y revisa lo que es un [mcve]. También te sugiero visitar [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor pon el ejemplo que hiciste con reduce, porque tengo una idea de cómo resolverlo así.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar lodash para esta clase de cosas

```
var filtered = _.uniqBy(data, 'Key');
```

Donde data sería tu array de lotes y Key el valor de la llave del objeto por el cual quieres filtrarlo.

Para la próxima intenta formular un poco mejor tu pregunta o intentar poner un poco mas de tu código para tener más contexto.